# Citrix webform file uploading, gives access denied

Tags: php, citrix

For some reason my form won't submit if a user is in a Citrix environment, with Internet Explorer as a browser.

The code for the form is:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://mywebsite.com/photo/upload" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input name="photo" type="file">
   <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

The console gives an error, pointing to the line of the form. With the error-message: "Access denied". Just that.

The website is written in PHP and hosted on a Linux server.

Is this something that isn't possible because of some rights users have on Citrix, or? Because it does work when a user uses Chrome in a browser.

Answer (score -1):

Is http://mywebsite.com/photo/upload on a separate domain than the form?  If so, the access-denied error message is stemming from the security issue of sending a POST message cross-domain opening the door to cross-domain-scripting attacks.

To make it work you may need to add something like:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
```

To the beginning of the http://mywebsite.com/photo/upload PHP code.  You would want to review that and set the actual origins, as the above code allows ANY domain to send GET and POST messages.

Comment: It is on the same domain. I already had the following in the .htaccess: 
```<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
 Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
 Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
</ifModule>``` - So that is not the solution.

Comment: Can you use a relative path then instead of the full URL?

Comment: Did not help. All forms are working in this way, except when a file should be uploaded.

Comment: Citrix may be filtering full paths instead of a relative one. Try changing it to a relative path instead. So, instead of http://mywebsite.com/photo/upload try just upload, or upload.php.

Comment: Straight from their website: Attempts to upload a 10 MB or larger file may fail when Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) and SQL Injection checks are enabled.  Found here: http://support.citrix.com/proddocs/topic/netscaler-release-notes-93/ns-rn-common-kwn-issues-wrk-arnds-93cl-con.html

Comment: My answer is a viable answer, you need to make sure that the URL is a relative path and something that is on the same domain.  I would even try using a file that includes an extension such as upload.php instead of just upload

Comment: Yea ok, but it is not working. Tried different paths, tried adding *.php, tried adding .html. It's not the solution. Sorry. :)

Comment: I'm not sure then, but it may be an Internet Explorer issue if you are using Citrix on Windows Server.